# use of unassigned variable c#

Tags: c#

What is the best way to solve the error **use of unassigned variable**? The following code contains error:

```
string[] Names;
Countries.Keys.CopyTo(Names, 0);
```

Here `Countries` is of type `Dictionary<string, string>`. Error comes for the `Names` array.

Comment: Names are not assigned. try string[] Names = new string[5];

Comment: But what if Keys have count more than 5 ?

Comment: The compiler isn't smart enough..

Comment: @user1574860 He should of course use the size he needs.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create an empty array to copy the values into:

```
string[] Names = new string[Countries.Keys.Count];
Countries.Keys.CopyTo(Names,0);
```

If you can use LINQ, you can do this as

```
string[] names = Countries.Keys.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the country set is a dictionary, for example:

```
string[] names = new string[countries.Count];
```

Regarding .NET coding conventions, local variables as well as private type members should be titled camel cased, thus use "name" instead of "Name" and "countries" instead of Countries, assuming Countries is not a property.

Answer (score 1):

it's better to use [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) construct, if it's possible, on initialization of some variable with some **it's** intiial value:

**For example** :

```
var x = default(int);
```

in your case, it could be

```
string[] s = default(string[]);
```

**EDIT**

Considering *edited question*, you have to carry about intializing *correctly*, as `default` value for reference-type would return `null`, which in your specific case, would generate exception.

So just initialize it like:

```
string[]  s=  new string[Countries.Keys.Count];
```

Comment: [This will throw an ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06x742cw.aspx).

Comment: default is kind of unnecessary when not working with generics. 'null' is much more concise then 'default(string[])'.

Comment: @Rawling: **wrong**. It depends on **what** is it *Countries.Keys* and *how* it's implemented.

Comment: @MrDosu: I would call this "coding preference". Someone likes it, someone not.

Comment: it says Countries is a Dictionary<string, string> in the question

Comment: My mistake. I meant [this will throw an ArgumentNullException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91e2z0hz.aspx).

Comment: `new string[Countries.Keys]` also makes no sense.

Comment: @Tigran If something just introduces complexity for no gain I wouldn't call it preference. The default keyword was explicitly created to assign default values in generic classes when you don't know if you have a reference or value type in front of you.

Comment: I also challenge you to write a `CopyTo` method with the signature described in the original question where passing a null array can do _anything_ useful.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize the array to overcome this:

```
string[]  Names =  new string[Countries.Keys.Count];
```